# tns create app-name --template tns-template-drawer-navigation-ng

Tags: tabs, navigation, nativescript

I use the Angular templete, fro this I run :

```
tns create app-name --template tns-template-drawer-navigation-ng
```

In fact I want to show this theme, like in photo:

[image]
The menu is in bootom.

But for me when I run coman, install this theme, like in photo.
The menu is in top:

[image]

Please, what is the diffrent? How to displey menu like in photo one. Menu in bootom.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template works properly. If you use NativeScript Sidekick you can see that the expected result for a template is different for iOS and Android. Your first screenshot is an iOS emulator, default iOS style is to have the menu at the bottom. In your second screenshot you show an Android emulator, the default Android style is to have the menu at the top.

This is quite common for such apps. If you'd want it to be the same for both devices then you'd have to remove the OS specific code.

[image: Screenshot from NativeScript Sidekick]

Comment: How to show menu like in iOS in emulator or mobile android??

Comment: You'd need to clarify your question for that. Currently there is no question nor any code shown. You may want to confirm my answer and open a new question for your actual problem. This question is technically answered since the expected behaviour is done